# Material UI InputAdornment not showing anything

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using MUI for the first time on a project. Trying to get InputAdornment to show a magnifying glass svg icon inside a TextInput. I'm following the example here: https://mui.com/components/text-fields/

Regardless of the content of the adornment, I cannot get anything to show up in the UI. In the inspector, the input adornment attribute looks like this `endadornment="[object Object]"`

My code is like this:

```
<TextField
    defaultValue={''}
    inputProps={{
        placeholder: 'Search',
        endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">any</InputAdornment>
    }}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: have you tried passing endAdornment to InputProps instead of inputProps?. They are different props applied to different subcomponents...

Comment: Wow I am speechless. That was it. Also that naming is horrible. Thank you!

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things

And believe me, folks, the latter needs special attention.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answered by cris_b in a comment. Turns out there is an `InputProps` prop and an `inputProps` prop on TextField.

The difference between the two according to the MUI text-field API [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/):

**inputProps**: object
[Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) applied to the `input` element.

**InputProps**: object
Props applied to the Input element. It will be a [FilledInput](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/filled-input/), [OutlinedInput](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/outlined-input/) or [Input](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/) component depending on the `variant` prop value.

Comment: Thanks man! You just saved my day! All I needed to do is just to wrap my text in label component like this:
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          <InputLabel>{fixedPlaceholderText}</InputLabel>
        </InputAdornment>

Comment: What If I have to use both like `inputProps` and `InputProps`?